# how to print local outputs in tensorflow federated?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I want to print local outputs of clients in the tensorflow federated tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a list of the values that go into the aggregations (e.g. into `tff.federated_mean`), one option would be to add additional outputs to `aggregate_mnist_metrics_across_clients()` to include metrics computed using [`tff.federated_collect()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_collect).

This might look something like:

```
@tff.federated_computation
def aggregate_mnist_metrics_across_clients(metrics):
  return {
      'num_examples': tff.federated_sum(metrics.num_examples),
      'loss': tff.federated_mean(metrics.loss, metrics.num_examples),
      'accuracy': tff.federated_mean(metrics.accuracy, metrics.num_examples),
      'per_client/num_examples': tff.federated_collect(metrics.num_examples),
      'per_client/loss': tff.federated_collect(metrics.loss),
      'per_client/accuracy': tff.federated_collect(metrics.accuracy),
  }
```

Which will get printed a few cells later when the computation runs:

```
state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
print('round  1, metrics={}'.format(metrics))

round  1, metrics=<...,per_client/accuracy=[0.14516129, 0.10642202, 0.13972603],per_client/loss=[3.2409852, 3.417463, 2.9516447],per_client/num_examples=[930.0, 1090.0, 730.0]>
```

**Note however**: if you want to know the value of a specific client, there is intentionally no way to do that. By design, TFF's language intentionally avoids a notion of client identity; there is desire to avoid making clients addressable.

Comment: If client address is not accessible, how to find and avoid some attacks such as meaningless or incorrect model update?  And since client address is inaccessible, I want to analyze the values of different clients, is this reasonable?

Comment: Determining how to defend against "bad" (and even defining what is "bad") updates is an active area of FL research. While TensorFlow Federated avoids a mapping of which client provided which update, its still possible to inspect (and treat differently) the updates on the server (this may change the implementation uses a secure multiple party communication technique though). The implementation of the FederatedAveraging algorithm include in TFF uses tff.federated_mean(), but constructing a custom tff.federated_reduce() that determines whether to include an update is a possible avenue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print something in 'client_update' function you can use `tf.print()`.