# Access Clients Loss while having keras tff NN models

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to obtain the losses of all clients in tensorflow model without luck. The answer to post [how to print local outputs in tensorflow federated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56334232/11621237)
suggests to create our NN model from scratch. However, I already have my keras NN model. So is there a way to still access the local client losses without having to build NN from scratch?

I tried to use tff.federated_collect(), but not sure how is that possible.

This is partly my attempt:

```
    trainer_Itr_Process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn_Federated,server_optimizer_fn=(lambda : tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learn_rate)),client_weight_fn=None)
    FLstate = trainer_Itr_Process.initialize()

    @tff.learning.Model
    def federated_output_computation():
        return{
            'num_examples': tff.federated_sum(metrics.num_examples),
            'loss': tff.federated_mean(metrics.loss, metrics.num_examples),
            'accuracy': tff.federated_mean(metrics.accuracy, metrics.num_examples),
            'per_client/num_examples': tff.federated_collect(metrics.num_examples),
            'per_client/loss': tff.federated_collect(metrics.loss),
            'per_client/accuracy': tff.federated_collect(metrics.accuracy),
            }
```

This is the error I received:

```
   @tff.learning.Model
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

`tff.learning.Model` is not a decorator for functions, it is the class interface used by the `tff.learning` module.

Probably the best way to change the implementation of [`tff.learning.Model.federated_output_computation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model#federated_output_computation) (what is recommended in [how to print local outputs in tensorflow federated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334232/how-to-print-local-outputs-in-tensorflow-federated)) is to create your own subclass of `tff.learning.Model`, that implements a different `federated_output_computation` property. This would be close to re-implementing `tff.learning.from_keras_model()`, except providing the custom metric aggregation; so looking at the implementation ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/46a551584281ceba6b8e2d66edd40a8dbd3ebcb8/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py#L86)) can be useful, but ingesting Keras models is non-trivial at the moment.